# Find out if a given string comes AFTER another string in a .txt file

Tags: python

I want to write a code that goes through a .txt file line by line and looks for strings that are provided in two lists like:

```
list1 = ["s1", "s2", "s3"]
list2 = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

If a value from list1 appears in the file after a value from list2 appears in the file, I want to remove the value from list1.

So for example. Look at the content of this .txt-File:

```
stuff
stuff
s1 stuff
s2
stuff string1 stuff
s1
```

-> Now I want to keep s2 (and s3 and all the other strings of that list) in my list and want s1 removed from that list as s1 appeared in the text after a string of list2.

I have written some code but I cannot get it to work as it does not filter anything.

```
list1 = ["s1", "s2", "s3"]
list2 = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        for table1 in list1:
            if table1 in line:
                for table2 in list2:
                    if table2 in line:
                        if table1 in list1:
                            list1.remove(table1)

print(list1)
```

Comment: you want this to be in immediate after or for all string from list1 whoever appear after list2 string anywhere below in file

Comment: You are checking the same line... In your example it looks like you want to check consecutive lines

Comment: @sahasrara62: Anywhere below in file

Comment: In the sample text you have two "s1"s, one after "stuff" and the other one after "string1". Do you need to remove both "s1"s or just the one after "string1"?

Comment: @CarlosGaldino: Neither: I dont want to remove anything from the txt file. I only want to filter list1. So in the example I want my list1 to look like this ["s2", "s3] -> s1 gets removed due to "string1" being present in the txt.file in a line before s1

Answer (score 0):

If the file only contains lines with one word as the example, you could use this:

```
list1 = ["s1", "s2", "s3"]
list2 = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  last = False
  for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if last and (line in list1):
      list1.remove(line)
    last = line in list2
  print(list1)
```

output:
['s2', 's3']

Comment: Unfortunately, many lines contain several words. Thanks for the effort though :)